# JQL -Filter of tickets that were transitioned end to end by the same user

Tags: jira, jql

I am searching for a JQL to show all Issues that didn´t changed the assigned User.

In theory  `NOT assignee CHANGED` works fine, but if the Ticket was Unassigned at a point the change from unassigned to assigned counts as a CHANGE off course.

Background is:

*I would like to have a Filter of tickets that were transitioned end to end by the same user..*

It would be fine if i could limit the assignee changed condition to a range of status transitions (i.e. exclude the change from backlog to open..) but i didn´t find a solution for a limitation on CHANGED other than time...

Any Ideas?

Comment: The problem is that issue can be transitioned without changing the assignee so I think assignee in query will not suffice

Comment: I think, that it is not possible just with jql. Are you interested, or is it possible for you to do it with a groovy script?

Comment: Sadly I won´t be able to run scripts nor plugins.. JQL might be the only thing I can use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, and this filter works fine for me. In my case I can not test what happens with issues with empty or null assignee due to i have restrictions on our jira so that that can not happen.

```
(assignee is not null) and !(assignee changed)
```

Regards,

Oldskultxo

Comment: Great!! Glad to help!